# useEffect unable to run in react native

Tags: react-native, redux

I am using redux in react native , When the state of redux changes, useEffect is not executed，
here is my code

```
const message = useSelector(state => {
    const { privateChat } = state
    const chatObj = privateChat.filter(s => s.user === replyer) // chatObj is an object
    console.log('changed')
    return chatObj[0]
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('message1', message)
   
  }, [message])
```

every time the 'changed' was printed, useEffect did not print out the data，I dont konw what went wrong

Comment: `useSelector` runs every time `state` changes, but `useEffect` runs only when `message` changes. With `console.log('changed')`, log `chatObj[0]` too to make sure it's changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
const privateChat = useSelector(state => state.privateChat);

const chatObj = privateChat.filter(s => s.user === replyer) // chatObj is an object
console.log('changed');

useEffect(() => { 
   console.log('message1', chatObj) 
}, [privateChat]);
```

Comment: thans for your help